# custom shell script: github keeps asking for password

Tags: shell, github

I would like to know how to stop GitHub from asking for password over and over while running a custom shell script.

I have an installation script for a project. It installs cordova plugins from private GitHub repositories. The file goes like this:

```
...
cordova plugin add https://github.com/some/repo1.git
cordova plugin add https://github.com/some/repo2.git
cordova plugin add https://github.com/some/repo3.git
cordova plugin add https://github.com/some/repo4.git
...
```

For every line that gets executed, the shell prompts for password. Is there a way to authenticate only once?

Answer (score -1):

You must use ssh urls instead of https.

```
cordova plugin add git@github.com:owner/repo1.git
cordova plugin add git@github.com:owner/repo2.git
cordova plugin add git@github.com:owner/repo3.git
cordova plugin add git@github.com:owner/repo4.git
```

Here is how to initialize your ssh configuration: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but it does not work with Cordova. I constantly get `Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.`.